# Is it true that government intervention is partly responsible for a decline in hanja usage?

Tags: history-of-korean

[The Wikipedia article on Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#History_of_Hangul) states that

> Beginning in the 1970s, hanja began to experience a gradual decline in
>   commercial or unofficial writing in the South due to government
>   intervention...

If true, what form did this intervention take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I guessed, a big factor was (not teaching Hanja in) the schools...

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanja
>
> South
>
> South Korean primary schools abandoned the teaching of hanja in 1971. It is taught in separate courses in South Korean high schools, separately from the normal Korean-language curriculum. Formal hanja education begins in grade 7 (junior high school) and continues until graduation from senior high school in grade 12. A total of 1,800 hanja are taught: 900 for junior high, and 900 for senior high (starting in grade 10).[4] Post-secondary hanja education continues in some liberal-arts universities.[5]  [ . . . ] .......
>
> Debate flared again in 2013 after a move by South Korean authorities to encourage primary and secondary schools to offer hanja classes. Officials said that learning Chinese characters could enhance students' Korean-language proficiency; protesters called the program "old-fashioned and unnecessary".[6]

Two other forms of "government intervention" I can imagine are:

- Revising guidelines so that fewer Chinese characters are used in govt documents
- Less and less emphasis on Hanja in examinations related to govt jobs, and public certifications (lawyers, doctors, diplomats, teachers, police, civil service, public servants, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In order to boost nationalism Park Chung Hee literally banned hanja from school and publications in the 70s, hence from that generation until now nobody knows hanja and do not want to learn it. Koreans like to say that they  stopped using hanja naturally, but they are ignorant of their own recent history or do not want to acknowledge it. They were just forced to forget hanja. It's an example of how a government can make its people more stupid and ignorant. Not knowing hanja means that all the documments and books written before the 60s cannot be read at ease anymore, making the people even more ignorant about their history.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Any links / references about the banning?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Although the information about the topic is quite scarce in English, there is a Korean-American blogger making a very good insight into it (while adressing original references in Korean)

Comment: Here is one very good article of his explaining the matter: https://kuiwon.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/on-hangul-supremacy-and-exclusivity-hangul-under-the-dictators/

Comment: That's rather funny, because I went to the middle school in the 80s (after Park was dead) and I clearly remember being taught Hanja at school, not to mention newspapers were practically filled with Hanja: e.g., http://ojsfile.ohmynews.com/STD_IMG_FILE/2016/0509/IE001959767_STD.jpg (first example I found by googling "1980 조선일보").  IIRC, when the newspaper Hankyoreh (한겨레신문) was founded in 1988, it made a splash by adopting all-Korean policy.  Gradually during the 90s other newspapers realized that there was no practical reason to pepper Hanja everywhere, and the use of Hanja greatly decreased.

Comment: The blog post you quote may have factual information but is very biased in assessment.  As a native speaker, I can confidently say that we simply stopped using Chinese characters because they were more cumbersome with marginal benefit.  About the only legitimate reason (disambiguation of homonyms) is easily solved once most Koreans use Hangul exclusively, because then ambiguous words are naturally avoided in search of clear meaning.  Once the ball started rolling, any actions by national leaders (dictator or not) could at best postpone the inevitable by a few years.

Comment: If the truly factual parts from that blog post could be agreed on and summarised, i think that could make a fascinating answer!

Comment: Yes. After Park Chung Hee died there were timid attempts to teach hanja again, but it became just optional, so many kids do not learn the characters. Korean ultranationalists like to think about hanja and hangul mixed script as something introduced by Japan and thetefore disregard it, but that is utterly lying.

Comment: And the newspaper stopped used hanja because people could not understand it anymore because thry were not taught to. And yes homonimous words can be avoided, but it seems you as well as hangeul supremacists are glad to see your own language impoverished.

Comment: You're selectively presenting facts that support your opinion.  When I went to middle/high school, Hanja classes were not optional.  Also it is well known that most documents written in Korean during the Joseon era used Hangul exclusively: for example see this image of 홍길동전: https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%ED%99%8D%EA%B8%B8%EB%8F%99%EC%A0%84#/media/File:Honggildongjeon.jpg

Comment: Back in the 80s, bookstores and libraries looked like this: http://pds8.egloos.com/pds/200804/08/24/c0039224_47fb71a277850.jpg  I couldn't find a higher quality picture, but you can easily see how many books still had Hanja in their titles.  As far as I know publishers were never forbidden from adding Hanja to their books, and that's exactly what they did for a very long time.  You claim that government intervention killed the practice, but the reality is that people voted with their wallets.

Comment: @topomorto If anyone wants to take the effort to do that, it's their choice, but honestly I don't think it would make a "fascinating" answer.  :/  It's very difficult to fix "lying by omission": why not start from a balanced source?  (Well, as they say, "comments are not for extended discussion," so let me bow myself out here.  I think I've said enough, and if anyone's still not convinced, they can look the information up themselves.)

Comment: @jick I may well look into some of these things more when I have my Korean support team around me :) This answer and the comments have at least brought up some things for me to ask them about, so I'm grateful for that! I would say that words like 'stupid' and 'ignorant' imply value judgements and thus look a bit out of place on stack exchange in a way that, say, statistics on Hanja literacy levels would not.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for using improper qualificative attacks, still @juck id right in that the government did not forbid the use of hanja privately, which I did not specify; still tye teaxhing of hanja was halted, the introduced again briefly in the 80s again, then halted one more time. If people are not taught when they are kids, it is very difficuly that they learn it voluntarly when they grow up, then it is just logical that publications stop using hanja when they say they audience reduced because of yhe ignorance of the characters, and the main blame of that relies in the government.

Comment: This answer and OP's comments are correct - the shift towards *Hangul* exclusivity was likely an artificial change due to nationalistic policies, analogous to a South Korean version of *Juche*. Jick's comments are extremely unconvincing; a decline in *hanja* usage in Korean does not explain why the South Korean government insists on similar changes that have nothing to do with Korean language usage, such as requesting that China changing the Chinese language name of *Seoul* to 首爾, or requesting that Japanese approximates Korean names by their Korean pronunciation rather than *on'yomi*.

Comment: I've never heard of another government doing anything remotely similar - even Pyongyang hasn't tried anything like this. It's unbelievable really, when you think about it - imagine if the Chinese government requested that the Korean language must refer to Chinese names using 음독......